# Provide functional code through an embeddable script tag

Tags: iframe, widget, embed

I have written a PHP widget for websites that helps websites become more accessible.

I want to share this with users, I do not want to make this a WordPress plugin as I want it to be open to any type of website using any CMS etc.

Is there a way I can wrap my widget code, php, javascript and styles into an iframe or something similar to be able to share an embeddable script tag with people so thy can easily copy and paste the script tag into their website and my widget would appear and work perfectly on their website?

I have tried to search SO for the answer but I just don't even really know what I am talking about fully to be able to search correctly. I looked at lots of iframe answers and options, but not sure if this is the correct option or route to take.

I want to share my widget with people, allow them to embed and use its functionality, but keep the source code secure and safe.

Thank you in advance to any help or guidance.